# CSJS XSP.partialRefreshGet does not seem to do the refresh

Tags: javascript, xpages, client-side

I have a xe:navigator (called navigator1) on an application layout in the Left Column. In the Right Column I have a dynamicContent control. in the onClick event of the navigator I do a partial refresh on navigator1 which works but the dynamicContent1 is not refreshed. I can do a full refresh and both will refresh, but at a performance price. I put this in the Client side of the onClick:

```
XSP.partialRefreshGet('#{id:dynamicContent1}');
return true
```

but when I do the dynamicContent1 is not refreshed. I think my syntax is correct. If on the server side I do a partial refresh on dynamicContent1 it refreshes it correctly but navigator1 is not refreshed. So the issue is can one do two partial refreshes on the same onClick event?

Comment: Tried adding both XSP.partialRefreshGet('#{id:dynamicContent1}'); and XSP.partialRefreshGet('#{id:navigator1}'); in the Client side and removed the SS partial refresh but still does not work.

Comment: In either firebug or chrome developer tools, on the network panel. Do you see a network request happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I'm reading your question correctly, this is just a timing issue: when you define client-side code and server code in the same event, the client-side code is always executed first. So it's refreshing your `dynamicContent` control *before* it executes the `navigator` event.

Move the CSJS code to the `onComplete` property of the `eventHandler`. This property isn't surfaced in the "pretty panels" for events, so you'll need to navigate directly to the `<xp:eventHandler />` tag (either in the Source XML or via the Outline), and you'll find `onComplete` listed under All Properties.

Placing the refresh code in `onComplete` will ensure that the second refresh doesn't occur until *after* the first one is completed, which will allow the second target to reflect any changes triggered by the event.

**Bonus tip:** you can also chain refreshes:

```
XSP.partialRefreshGet("#{id:div1}", {
    onComplete: function() {
        XSP.partialRefreshGet("#{id:div2}", {
            onComplete: function() {
                XSP.partialRefreshGet("#{id:div3}", {
                    onComplete: function() {
                        XSP.partialRefreshGet("#{id:div4}");
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
```

This allows you to refresh as many targets as you want, but the same rule applies: if you need any of the targets to be "aware" of changes to data or components made within an event, you'll need to trigger the start of the chain in the `onComplete` attribute of that event, *not* as the client-side code of the event itself.

Comment: So to avoid any confusion it would be best to execute all the oartialRefreshgets in a nested form as above and not do the Server Side partial refresh. Thanks

Comment: here is the code from the eventHandler on the navigator - 
<xp:eventHandler event="onItemClick" submit="true" refreshMode="complete">
   <xp:this.onComplete>
   <![CDATA[#{javascript:XSP.partialRefreshGet("#{id:navigator11}", {onComplete: function() {
        XSP.partialRefreshGet("#{id:dynamicContent1}");}});}]]>
         </xp:this.onComplete>
   <xe:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:getComponent("dynamicContent1").show(context.getSubmittedValue());
sessionScope.put("ssSelectedView", context.getSubmittedValue());}]]>
   </xe:this.action>
  </xp:eventHandler>
will continue in next post

Comment: If I run it with anything but full UpDate I get an error XSP can not be found. Of course it works with full UpDate even with out the onComplete code. The FUll UpDate takes too long and I want to speed things up.

Comment: The "XSP cannot be found" error is because you're *computing* what the client JavaScript should be for `onComplete` instead of just entering client JavaScript. As a result, it's trying to execute `XSP.partialRefreshGet()` in SSJS, and `XSP` is not defined in SSJS.

Comment: For convenience, I've created a simple pattern page that demonstrates what I *think* you're trying to do: http://timtripcony.com/demo/patterns.nsf/pattern_multipleRefreshTargets.xsp The page includes a link where you can download the source code.

Comment: Tim - Thanks so much. Got it working! I needed to do the partial refresh on the onClick event and refresh the navigator1. This makes sure the sessionScope variable is correctly set. Then in the onComplete refresh the dynamicContent1 that uses the sessionScope variable to determine what is to be displayed in the dynamicContent.

Comment: On some further testing being able to do the two partial refreshes take about 1/2 (or less) the time of a full Update that I was having to otherwise do. Can be a significant performance issue. Thanks again Tim for your willingness to help.